# Using two HAVINGs in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large csv log file with the following header:

`CustomerID` , `Date` , `URL` , ....

I want to find all those `customers` who had visited at least 2 `distinct URLS` exactly in 2 days within the last 3 days.

What would be the SQL command ,

I though of this one : (how the date part looks : `GETDATE()-4` is not important at the moment)

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM log 
WHERE DATE > (GETDATE() - 4) 
GROUP BY (CustomerID, DATE, URL) 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE)) = 2 
AND HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT(URL))) > 2
```

Comment: mysql.org search on "SELECT syntax". It explains all kinds of things like the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 5):

Just miss out the having keyword so like

```
Having condition1 > val1 and condition2 >val 2
```

Sorry I'm on a phone so can't copy and paste that well

Comment: So the rest is ok ? I don't have access to a RDBMS right now , that's why I want to check it before running it

Comment: As your grouping by both of them the distinct may not be needed but it looks fine